# Can not access camera in ios 9 for AVCaptureDevice.

Tags: iphone, ios9, xcode7, avcapturedevice

I have been working on application which allows to use device camera using **AVCaptureDevice**. It was working perfectly for **ios version < 9** before, but now for ios 9 when I access camera from application, it just shows black screen. I can not even access user photos from application.

Main part is for my application I can not find camera option privacy setting in settings. Even I am not getting apple default permission access pop up option.

Can you please help me out here?

Answer (score 7):

With iOS 9, you should enter your app name with key: "Bundle Display Name" in Info.plist.

Thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32880876/4628777

Change this

[image: Info.plist]

to this

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: Why downvoted? A missing Bundle Display Name is a valid reason for not showing the permission popup.

Answer (score 1):

Older projects does not have the bundle display name property at all.

In this case, follow these steps:

1. Open Info.plist as Source Code.
2. Add these two lines at the end of the file
   CFBundleDisplayName
   YorAppName
3. Save & Rejoice!

The name you will state here will be used in the popup requesting the user for permissions.

**Note:** Make sure to search for CFBundleDisplayName property before adding a new property.

Comment: Never thought this could be issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is also another item you need to change in info.plist. Under the information property list, add another key work "privacy - Camera Usage Description". This solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have also same issue happend. But after resloved it. You have to delete your current app in the device. You have to test app on next day. Actuall that permission dialog some time not asking in iOS 9 next day when you test your app definatly you get the permisson dialog in your app.

Comment: Did you wait a full 24 hours, Bhavin?

Comment: Can't you just set the permission via Settings? I'm having same issue but this didn't resolve it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

After a few tests that the old info.plist was the problem. I replaced the info.plist for a one created in a new project and it worked for me.

Regards.