# "PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization" not asking permissions in iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, phphotolibrary, ios-permissions

It's not asking permissions for gallery in iOS 9 but in iOS 8 it works fine. Maybe  I need any permission key in `info.plist`?

```
 PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status) -> Void in

 })
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue appear in iOS 9 when your application Info.plist file contains a key: "CFBundleDisplayName" with empty string value.

You can enter your app name there and it should work.

key {Bundle display name} value $(PRODUCT_NAME)

same problem founded there and solution 
[App does not have access to your photos or videos iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768012/app-does-not-have-access-to-your-photos-or-videos-ios-9)

Comment: really that is very good answer! it help me a lot, too much thanks !

Comment: After adding Bundle display name to plist, delete app, cleaned, removed DerivedData... Nothing... Not woking. Can't get it to show the permission popup again.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YlgHUFC.png and try fill Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description it's work for my case

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a key in your info.plist.  First be sure:

- Import the Photos.framework via Link Binary With Libraries
- Import Photos into your View Controller

  ```
      let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()

      if status == .Authorized {            
          //  Permission Authorized       
      } else if status == .Restricted {            
          //  Permission Restricted
      } else if status == .NotDetermined {        
          //  Permission Not Determined
      } else if status == .Denied {        
          //  Permission Denied
      }
  ```

Comment: and if we get into the condition of not determined how to we get the iOS permission prompt to appear?