# iOS 9 - Request Camera authorisation for photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

I have an app which needs to be able to take photos (not videos). I was looking online to find out how to detect if the user has granted permission to the camera.

After a while I found that you could use `AVAuthorizationStatus` to figure this out. However, on the Apple docs its says:

> Calling this method with any media type other than AVMediaTypeVideo or
>   AVMediaTypeAudio raises an exception.

So what if I want to take a photo then? How do I do that? There is no `AVMediaTypePhoto` and I have not been able to find out how to authorise camera access in any other way.

This is the authorisation example code I found online, but I don't know if it will work if you just want to take pictures.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) { // authorized

    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied){ // denied

    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted){ // restricted


    }
    else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){ // not determined

        [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
            if(granted){ // Access has been granted ..do something

            } else { // Access denied ..do something

            }
        }];
    }
```

**Update 1**

I was also looking into the `PHPhotoLibrary` framework, but that only provides access to the photo library, not the camera.

Comment: Yes,  it will work. Did you try the above code in actual device ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Ahhh.... I'm so stupid... I was testing this on the simulator. Just tested it on a real iDevice and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the code in my question does work, I was just being stupid and testing it on the iOS simulator and not on a real iDevice...... I think I need a coffee break :)

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 9, You should enter your app name with key: "Bundle Display Name" in Info.plist.

Thanks to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32880876/4628777

Change this

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xkfW.jpg)

to this

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNbYI.jpg)

Comment: Thanks if someone could help me to change url to image.

Answer (score 0):

Set **CFBundleDisplayName = "AppName"** in Info.plist for iOS 9

Comment: Where is that in the plist? I typed it in and it corrected just to "Bundle display name". I assume it's the same