# Camera shows Black Screen when using SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios

when I am loading web page using SFSafariViewController, and web page has option to upload photos. 
I am able to upload photos from Photo Library but when I select to Take Photo or Video, camera loads up with black screen. I checked the setting "Camera is allowed for my app"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 9 - xcode 7 - SFSafariViewController - Image Upload - Camera Black Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930409/ios-9-xcode-7-sfsafariviewcontroller-image-upload-camera-black-screen)