# How to get user permissions every time in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9, user-permissions

I am doing application related to camera,photos and GPS.Whenever i open the app i need to ask the permissions to user on every installation.This is working fine in iOS 10.But in iOS 9,if i uninstall and install again,permission popups are not coming,but in iOS 10 it's working correctly.Please suggest how to get the popups every installation in iOS 9 also.

Comment: Check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768012/app-does-not-have-access-to-your-photos-or-videos-ios-9

Comment: Not working if we add the bundledisplayname

Answer (score 2):

This issue will appear if in your "info.plist" file contains "CFBundleDisplayName" with empty string value. Just enter your app name there. Also if that is not working try to reset the settings by below 3 way,

First option

As described in [Technical Note TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html) :

You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:

Delete your app from the device.
Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.

Second option

When you delete an app the iOS keeps the permission of your app mapped to your app's bundle id, it keeps the data for day. So you can also change your app's bundle id to test it out.

Third Option

Reset all location and privacy permissions : Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy. Note that this will reset all location and privacy permissions for all the apps on that device.

Comment: Where is @rmaddy comment in this question ?

Answer (score 1):

With iOS 9 it will take around 2 days to remove the permission from OS. Within 2 days if you install that app again which you installed previously and accepted permissions previously then it will not ask for the permission again. If the install is after 2 days then it will ask for permission.

If you want it to give a try then you can check it after increasing the date with 2-3 days then install application. Then it will definitely ask for the permission.

Comment: Programatically anythings shall we do for permissions in iOS 9?

Comment: No, this permissions are from the SDK's only, you can't prompt the user for this permissions

Comment: Any private API to do this?

Comment: As of now i don't know about any private API which will used to display permission alert .